# Problem making a GET on my site when it is entered via www (react + django)

Tags: django, https, django-rest-framework, httprequest, http-redirect

I have a django application that uses React on some of its pages (Only one server in django that have a react page). In my pages in React, I make HTTP requests to django api using Django Rest Framework.

This application is already running, and in it I noticed a problem. If I enter the site without "www", log in normally and access the pages via react, everything works perfectly.

However, when I use "www" to access the site, it first makes me redo the login (it does not save that I was already logged in) and also, when accessing the pages in react, the GET request gives the `403 error`, which Credentials were not provided, however, without the "www" it works fine.

DRF data in *settings.py*:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

I really don't know if it is a DRF problem, something that was missing from the request, or some HTTPS redirect problem.

Would anyone have any idea what it might be? Thank you!